# Picture from wrong directory included

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, folders

This question is somehow related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309486/graphicspath-images-with-duplicate-filenames-different-folder-locations) but I'm looking for a solution on class basis. I have my own texmf tree with different classes like this:

```
├── mytexmf/
│   └── tex/
│       └── latex/
│           ├── class_1/
│           │   └── Pictures/
│           │       ├── A.pdf
│           │       └── B.pdf
│           └── class_2/
│               └── Pictures/
│                   ├── A.pdf
│                   └── C.pdf
└── mytexprojects/
    └── project_a/
        └── Pictures/
            └── D.pdf
```

Inside the `class_1.cls` file I set `\graphicspath{{./Pictures}}`. When I compile my tex file inside `project_a`, this allows me to use the same graphicspath and gives me access to `A/B/D.pdf`. However, sometimes `A.pdf` from the `class_2` subfolder is used.
If I  understand correctly, I could rename the `Pictures` directory for each class in the texmf directory to a unique name to only import from there.

Assuming I change my directory structure like this:

```
├── mytexmf/
│   └── tex/
│       └── latex/
│           ├── class_1/
│           │   └── Pictures_1/
│           │       ├── A.pdf
│           │       └── B.pdf
│           └── class_2/
│               └── Pictures_2/
│                   ├── A.pdf
│                   └── C.pdf
└── mytexprojects/
    └── project_a/
        └── Pictures/
            └── D.pdf
```

And in `class_1.cls` changing the import to read

`\graphicspath{{./Pictures}{./Pictures_1}}`

will this make sure, when I include `A.pdf` I will not accidentially use the one from `class_2`?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603949/overriding-texmf-with-graphicspath?rq=1 this might be a better option than what I'm trying.

Comment: latex will find A.pdf  in the texmf tree independant of your graphicspath settings and which one it finds first is undefined. You would have to do something like \includegraphic{class_1/Pictures/A} to ensure that you get the right one.

Comment: Perfect, I'll do this then. All this images are anyway part of a macro, so I can simply change all paths to be explicit.